# Verify if the index is used

Tags: mongodb, database

Assert that we have an index on people's ages. Will it be used when we find documents by some other, unindexed field (like name) and then after find we attempt to sort? Are there any rules of thumb as when does an index apply?

```
db.people.find( { 'name' : "Peter" } ).sort( { age: 1 } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [indexes introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/indexes-introduction/) and [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).

Btw: It is always a bad idea to search on non-indexed fields. The indexed sort field does not rescue you in that case. On the other hand there will be only one index used at each time. Means: If you are searching on an indexed field (or fields) your sort will not use any index if it cannot use the same index, which was used for the search.